# SharePoint workflow 2010 platform works, but SharePoint workflow 2013 platform does not in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

I have created simple email sending workflow in platform 2013 in SharePoint Designer 2013 and I have set it to start when item is created.

I've saved and published it. It was published successfully, but it does not work on SharePoint site.

I've created the same workflow in platform 2010 in SharePoint designer 2013. It was published successfully and works fine on the site. Email is also sent to the email address given in the workflow

Why workflow 2013 platform does not work in the site?

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to publish SharePoint 2013 workflow, then it's probably configured correctly in your farm. Is this problem with all workflows or specific to sending emails?

There's a known limitation in SharePoint 2013 workflows and app model - you can only send mail to internal addresses (addresses of valid SharePoint users).

It's a security feature actually. It prevents apps from sending spam.

Workaround to this problem is using SharePoint 2010 workflows.

Comment: No I'm new to this sharepoint so i was did simple email sending workflow using internal email address only and configured the workflow manager correctly.

But in the get-WFFarmStatus my workflow servicefrontend is stopped backend is running .is there any problem because of this "Stopped" Status

Thanks, beaulah